# How do I extract the underlying HTML dom element from a TestCafe Selector?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying out TestCafe and having problems locating some of my elements. I want to be able to, for debugging purposes, print out whatever element(s) that TestCafe has found with a particular Selector so I can compare them against the DOM that exists.

I have already tried reading the documentation and running this code:

```
const a = await Selector('span', { timeout: 20000 }).withText('some text');
console.log(a);
```

However, when I run this code, all I get is a printout of some internal TestCafe type like so:

```
[Function: __$$clientFunction$$] {
  with: [Function],
  nth: [Function],
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who wants the answer for later, to get the actual html element, you need to call the Selector, ie:

```
const a = await Selector('span', { timeout: 20000 }).withText('text'))()
console.log(a)
```

This is because `Selector` creates a function that testcafe uses and can execute internally to get elements, but if you want to manually do that, you need to call it.

example output

```
{
  nodeType: 1,
  textContent: 'Before or on',
  childNodeCount: 1,
  hasChildNodes: true,
  childElementCount: 1,
  hasChildElements: true,
  tagName: 'span',
  visible: true,
  focused: false,
  attributes: {
    'data-role': 'filtercell',
```

Comment: Calling the selector won't print the actual dom element, but still an abstraction from TestCafe. Methods such as innerHTML are still not present in this abstraction.